# 'Bitmap' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

Tags: c#, bitmap

I am getting the following compile-time error:

`The type or namespace name 'Bitmap' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Here is my code:

```
BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
```

Answer (score 55):

You have to add `System.Drawing` to your references so in solution
Explorer rightclick on  References and click on Add References and in
assemblies find `System.Drawing` and click **OK**

Comment: Should be set as best answer, at least it was for me.

Comment: When would this happen automatically and when do I need to do this manually? Why does it need to be done?

Answer (score 38):

Today (2020 year) it's nuGet package `System.Drawing.Common.dll`. 
To add it: right click on project name (at solution explorer) --> "Manage NuGet packages" --> choose "Browse" label at the top --> search for "System.Drawing.Common" --> install it.

Answer (score 6):

Add PresentationCore as a reference.

### How-to:

1. Click the .NET tab.
2. Locate and click the PresentationCore item from the list.
3. Click the OK button.

### Result:

The PresentationCore assembly appears in the References list for your project.

### Finally:

Add a using directive for the System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace at the top of the file, which is where `BitmapImage` lives.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
```

Comment: Nice comprehensive answer - fixed for `BitmapImage` instead of `Bitmap`

Comment: The windows compatibility nuget package would be the recommended method as when writing this comment. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you need to add:

```
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
```

Comment: The more appropriate is `System.Drawing`

Comment: Perhaps instead of trying to add the library Name yourself (at the top, with "using"), try add the actual reference to the Library. That is, add reference to "System.Drawing"

Comment: @DaneBalia i already did. add the reference manually. but it still wont work. im not joking. is there any other reason for it?

Comment: No, there is a serious problem somewhere if this basic functionality does not work. Are you having the problem with either libraries as well? What version of Visual Studio are you running? What version of Windows? Do you perhaps not have a corrupt VS installation?

Comment: Just a missing assembly reference to PresentationCore.dll.

Comment: `System.Drawing` is incorrect - `BitmapImage` is in the `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` namespace, and is in `PresentationCore.dll` which should be in the GAC in .NET 3 and later.