# Where does Chrome store extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, path

I looked in:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions
```

for unpacked extensions, but that folder is empty for me.

For newer versions, where does Chrome store the files?

Comment: Related: [Where to find extensions installed folder for Google Chrome on Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17377337/1287812)

Comment: c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\<VERSION>\Extensions\

Comment: OR => C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions

Answer (score 376):

### Storage Location for Unpacked Extensions

Extension engine does not explicitly change their location or add a reference to its local paths, they are left in the place where there are selected from in all **Operating Systems**.

**Ex:** If I load a unpacked Extension from `E:\Chrome Extension` the unpacked Extension is still in the same location

### Storage Location for Packed Extensions

Navigate to `chrome://version/` and look for **Profile Path**, it is your default directory and Extensions Folder is where all the **`extensions, apps, themes`** are stored. (If you have several browser profiles set up in Chrome, you will want to view the `chrome://version/` page from the profile where the extension is installed.)

#### Examples

##### Windows

If my **Profile Path** is `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` then my storage directory is:

```
C:\Users\<Your_User_Name>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions
```

##### Linux

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/
```

##### MacOS

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions
```

##### Chromium

```
~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions
```

Comment: On os x `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions`

Comment: A partner has this extensions **Page Speed Insight https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pagespeed-insights-by-goo/gplegfbjlmmehdoakndmohflojccocli** but not it is deprecated, and I canno download it. Maybe can I copy folder extensions from my PC partner?

Comment: But when you alter something in these files, immediately chrome will mark the extension as Corrupted and will ask you to "Repair" it by reinstalling

Comment: Windows path, easier copy paste: %LOCALAPPDATA%/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Extensions

Comment: I got a best solution form this page [http://uncaughterror.com/programming/javascript/how-to-find-chrome-extension-location-in-our-computer/](http://uncaughterror.com/programming/javascript/how-to-find-chrome-extension-location-in-our-computer/)

Comment: If you make and extension and pack it, it does not go to this folder.

Comment: There is no extensions dir in chrome Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: On Windows, hold Win key, then press R to run Run. Type %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions

Comment: There are subfolders with long hex ids instead of human-readable names in extensions folder. You can open extension settings and find hex id of an extension in the address bar.

Comment: Chromium isn't where specified

Comment: there is no folder "Default" in my folder structure a stop at User Data

Answer (score 22):

Since chrome has come up with the multiple profiles you will not get it directly in `C:\Users\<Your_User_Name>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions` but you have to first type `chrome://version/` in a tab and then look out for Profile path inside that and after you reach to your profile path look for Extensions folder in it and then folder with the desired extension Id

Comment: Looking in chrome://version helps on browsers other than "Chrome", such as Opera or Chromium, this was helpful - thanks.

Answer (score 17):

For my Mac, extensions were here:

`~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/`

if you go to `chrome://extensions` you'll find the "ID" of each extension. That is going to be a directory within Extensions directory. It is there you'll find all of the extension's files.

Answer (score 6):

For older versions of windows (2k, 2k3, xp)

```
"%Userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions"
```

Comment: The environment variable `%AppData%` is incorrect, it resolves to `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming`. The environment variable you're looking for is `%LocalAppData%`, which resolves to `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local`. So the full thing would be `%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions`.

Comment: I don't use windows vista, 7 or 8..  My post was only about 2k through 2k3

Comment: Windows XP : `C:\Documents and Settings\<Your_User_Name>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 5\Extensions`

Comment: The answer is STILL incorrect, since the question is about _unpacked_ extensions.

Answer (score 5):

For Chrome on Mac, if you have multiple profiles, you can find it under your profile folder, either `Default` or `Profile #`. i.e either

`~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/`
 or 
`~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/<Profile 1>/Extensions/`

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to do right click on the chrome icon and then go to shortcut tab (according to windows 10). You will see there "Target", copy the path and remove "chrome.exe".

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit late, but you can find it (windows 10 chrome 83)

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\<your profile>\Extensions
```

Chrome now store it per profile. If you only have one profile, it's in a folder called `Default`

Answer (score 0):

This link "[Finding All Installed Browsers in Windows XP and Vista – beware 64bit!](http://rhizohm.azurewebsites.net/-finding-all-installed-browsers-in-windows-xp-and-vista-ndash-beware-64bit-/)" may be useful for Windows as suggested by "[How to find all the browsers installed on a machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370732/how-to-find-all-the-browsers-installed-on-a-machine)".

The installed web browsers are saved in this registry,

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Clients\StartMenuInternet.