# Where to find extensions installed folder for Google Chrome on Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I can not find them under ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/; Where are they?

- Mac Pro 10.8.4
- Chrome Version 26.0.1410.65

Comment: On my Mac, they're located in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions`

Comment: Just missing \ above here is correct cd: `cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions`

Answer (score 273, accepted):

The *default* locations of Chrome's profile directory are documented in the [*User Data Directory* article](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/user_data_dir.md) on Googlesource.com. (When this article was written in 2013, the User Data Directory article was at [chromium.org](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory).) It says there,

> To determine the user data directory for a running Chrome instance:
>
> 1. Navigate to chrome://version
> 2. Look for the Profile Path field. This gives the path to the profile directory.
> 3. The user data directory is the parent of the profile directory.

For Chrome on Mac, it's

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default
```

The actual location can be different, by [setting](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory#TOC-Running-from-a-Custom-Location) the `--user-data-dir=path/to/directory` flag.
If only one user is registered in Chrome, look in the `Default/Extensions` subdirectory. Otherwise, look in the `<profile user name>/Extensions` directory.

If that didn't help, you can always do a custom search.

1. Go to `chrome://extensions/`, and find out the ID of an extension (32 lowercase letters) (if not done already, activate "Developer mode" first).

   [image: Chrome UI showing extension ID with 32 letters]
2. Open the terminal, cd to the directory which is most likely a parent of your Chrome profile (if unsure, try `~` then `/`).
3. Run `find . -type d -iname "<EXTENSION ID HERE>"`, for example:

   ```
   find . -type d -iname jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin
   ```

Result:

> [image: ./Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin]

Comment: The path is ./Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/ ; enter this into prompt poped up via 

With the dot(.) instead of ~ , I found it.

Comment: on Mac Open a Finder window on Menu Go > Go to Folder type or paste "~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default" and hit Go

Comment: On chrome 80xx, MacOS 10.15.3 -->
/Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1/Extensions/

Comment: @airbai The dot just refers to the current directory, so one should never rely on a path that begins with that. `~` refers to the “home” directory, or `/Users/[username]`.

Comment: @Frungi, it's perfectly fine to work with paths starting with `.` as long as you're aware it means the current working directory.

Comment: @JohnPancoast Which is of no help whatsoever when you don’t know what *someone else’s* working directory was at the time the command was entered, and more than likely that person didn’t even know it themself. Full paths (beginning with `/` or `~/`) always work. Relative paths (beginning with `./` or pretty much anything else) depend entirely on what `cd` commands preceded their use. Also, the `./` is wholly unnecessary.

Comment: @Frungi, I said that `.` is fine to pass to `find` _as long as you're aware that `.` means your current working directory_ (i.e., the last place you cd'd to). The `find` command accepts directories to search and it will recursively descend those directory trees so telling people that they should _always_ search their entire home directory is not useful. It's perfectly fine to use `find` to search `.` or `..` or  `~` or `~/foo` or `/bar/baz` as long as you're aware of what these paths are and you're aware of the implications of the command(s) and args you're running.

Comment: @Frungi, TL;DR `find` is meant to search _any_ path based on your needs, and it will be more performant if you search lower paths. It's more useful to tell people what certain characters mean in *nix rather than making absolute statements on the paths they should search.

Comment: @JohnPancoast Sorry for taking so long to respond. Also sorry for being unclear—I never meant to imply that `.` ought never be used. That would be silly. I was taking issue with the *specific use* by the OP, naming an “absolute” location relative to an unknowable one (please double-check whom my original comment was replying to). And I stand by my position that the use of `./foo/` rather than `foo/` is just unnecessary and unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: @Frungi, Ahh, I completely misunderstood to begin with and agree with you. My mistake. Cheers.

Answer (score 25):

You can find all Chrome extensions in below location.

```
/Users/{mac_user}/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions
```

Comment: Yes, this one worked for me in OSX 10.13.6, but the first answer didn't

Answer (score 16):

For **Mac EI caption/Mac Sierra**, Chrome extension folders were located at

```
/Users/$USER/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Profile*/Extensions/
```

Comment: I don't see `Profile*/Extensions/` its `Default/Extensions/` as @krishna_5c3 suggested

Comment: This answers is correct in 2022 if your Chrome installation has more than 1 profile.

Answer (score 5):

With the new App Launcher YOUR APPS (not chrome extensions) stored in `Users/[yourusername]/Applications/Chrome Apps/`

Comment: Any documentation / announcement links?

Comment: I found out my issue was related, and the information above helped - but was due to my own doing.  I keep ~/Library/Application actually as a link on Dropbox - as I have other smaller apps in there.  The OS X Alias had been set instead of a soft link, making Launcher not function.  Removed alias and set a soft link....works now.

Answer (score 4):

Go to `chrome://version` and get the right profile path.
[image]

In this folder you can find the extensions assigned to your profile by their id.

To find an extension id, enable the Developer mode in the extension page (`chrome://extensions`).
[image]

The id is now displayed within the extension details.
[image]

Source: https://www.maketecheasier.com/view-source-code-chrome-extension/

Comment: Thank you Ricardo, by far the best answer to understand how to find the Extensions folder on any computer!

Answer (score 3):

They are found on either one of the below locations depending on how chrome was installed

- When chrome is installed at the user level, it's located at:

`~/Users/<username>/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions`

- When installed at the root level, it's at:

`/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions`