# Which file under Chrome's Extension directory gives details about the name and version of the Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

I had gone through the below post on StackOverflow and I know where the chrome extensions are saved in the directory path, in MAC

[Where to find extensions installed folder for Google Chrome on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377337/where-to-find-extensions-installed-folder-for-google-chrome-on-mac#)

But my question was, the directory path usually ends into the  directory (which has several files and subdirectories)

Which file under this gives me the actual name of the Extension and its version?

For example say `jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin` is the extension id folder under  `/Users/$USER/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/`. Which exact file should I look inside here to know the name and version of the extension ?

I need this to write a script , so please don't give GUI based solution. I need it on CLI

Comment: It's inside manifest.json but beware the `"name"` field may contain a special token like `__MSG_something__` that links to `something` inside messages.json file in a corresponding _locales subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `manifest.json` in that file you will find all information about [chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest)

```
/Users/$USER/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/hash_of_your_selected_extenstion/manifest.json
```