# Chrome 84 - find extension folder

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377337/where-to-find-extensions-installed-folder-for-google-chrome-on-mac) because I was looking for a way to inspect my unpacked extension during dev process. I've noticed that in the Extension folder there are only the google extension like gmail chromecast ecc, but no one of my extensions is present. I'm running chrome 84.0.4147.125 for macOS, maybe they changed something and the extension are saved into another place? Anyone can help me please

Comment: Unpacked extensions aren't copied anywhere. They are running directly from where you loaded them.

Comment: @wOxxOm ah, ok I didn't know that. Thanks for the clarification.