# Remove All Chrome Extensions While Reinstalling Google-Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Recently, I have installed an annoying chrome extension (http://www.buntai.com/). Thanks to this extension, every time I open a new window in google chrome, it will minimize immediately, which made me not able to use chrome anymore.

Therefore, I tried to reinstall google chrome in order to get rid of the google chrome extension(I cannot remove it directly in chrome://extensions/ because I cannot open that page using chrome.)

However, it did not work. When I reinstalled google chrome, the extension was still there.

I am not sure why reinstalling chrome would not remove the extensions and I would like to know if there is another approach to remove the chrome extensions.

Comment: Try to open Chrome in incognito mode.  Open properties of Chrome link and past  --incognito as tail of target. Other option you may try is --disable-extensions.  If this work try then to access chorme://entension to remove that malicious extension. If this doesn't work you may try to hard remove the extension folder from his location. In my case extension are stored in C:\Users\<your user>\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\Default\Extensions

Comment: @Robbi. Thanks for the reply! However, currently, I am facing the following issues. (1) In incognito mode, extensions cannot be removed (2) I am using a MacBook and I do not know where is the folder of the malicious extension.

Comment: This thread coulb help you to find the path of the extensions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377337/where-to-find-extensions-installed-folder-for-google-chrome-on-mac