# Is it possible to over-write css in a chrome-extension locally?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a speed-reading app for chrome. I love it, though the typography could be improved for better ease of use. Is it possible to change the css of my instance of a chrome-extension?

Comment: Is it open-source? If so, send the patch!

Comment: You said it's an app, but you gave your question the google-chrome-extension tag. If it's an extension, then you could write another extension that adds yet more CSS on top of whatever CSS it's applying to the page. The C stands for cascading, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to manually edit the files in the [extension's directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14544700/2336725).  However, any published updates to the extension will overwrite your edits, so I would recommend backing up your changes.