# How to restore OneTab list of tabs after computer crash?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My computer crashed and I reinstall it over a new disk with chrome and the OneTab extension.
However, I can't find where OneTab is storing my data under my former disk.
I used this answer [Where does Chrome store extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543896/where-does-chrome-store-extensions) to go to the folder but there is no file dated close to the computer crash (and I used it on a daily basis).

Comment: if you are here, but you were looking for Firefox information. There is an [official page for it](http://www.one-tab.com/firefoxRestore).

Comment: I've moved to a different tool because Firefox has converted the extension data storage to a db file.. https://superuser.com/a/1714380/388883

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I found it after using onetab and than searching for all files changed on that minute...
So to restore one-tab from one computer to another you need to do this:

- use one-tabe
- search for `C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage`
- find these 2 files:

  - `chrome-extension_chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall_0.localstorage-journal`
  - `chrome-extension_chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall_0.localstorage`
- kill chrome so you will be able to back up 2 files in the directory
- change the recent changed files extantion
- copy the old 2 files from your backup to the folder
- restart chrome

Comment: I didn't understand the "change the recent changed files extantion" point, could you explain please? Which files do we need to change and what extension should we use?

Comment: just copy and replace, take a look at  Fotis Dimanidis's comment if you have multiple profiles

Comment: There must be some other possible location for OneTab to store its data. It's working properly on my Vivaldi browser, but among the four `chrome-extension_*.localstorage` files I can find on my entire disk, none of them seem to contain its data.

Comment: When reopening Chrome, it's possible to press the Undo closed tab keyboard shortcut `CMD + shift + t` keys on a Mac.  This often brings back the last Chrome session.  Sometimes you'll see a blank OneTab window as well as the recovered window.

Comment: It appears the extension files are in a new location as of 2021 June:  c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\google\chrome\user data\default\local extension settings.  You should copy the entire folder chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall to the same location on the new computer.

Answer (score 10):

Restore OneTab on Mac

Bailed me out when after using Cocktail (a system cleaning utility) to clear out logs/caches, etc.

The two files mentioned above for PC above are the same for Mac.

The same file path is used on the Mac:

`/Users/your-user-name/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage`

- Quit Chrome.
- Select the two files in the finder.
- Enter a Time Machine back up; it will automatically locate them,
- Choose the latest date before you wiped out OneTab,
- Do a Restore, copy over the old ones.

That's it. Back to normal.

Comment: In a multi-user Chrome setup the files lie in:
/Users/your-user-name/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Profile 1/Local Storage

Comment: Which "the two files" are you referring to?

Comment: The instruction totally saved my day! I think these should put into the official FAQ page of OneTab extension.

Comment: @AlejandroIglesias Could be any two files in `/Users/your-user-name/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage`. It will helps you to locate to the path in Time Machine.

Comment: i lost all my one tab after upgrading macos to 10.14.5, then i restore /Users/your-user-name/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Local Storage/leveldb (remember backup first) from timemachine, and the miss tabs are back.

Comment: I got the leveldb folder and contents copied, is there a way to read it in a human language?  My company have blocked all chrome extensions so no failure has occurred but unclear on to get the last good copy