# Editing a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, edit

I use the extension New Tab Wallpaper for Google Chrome. I am wondering if it's possible to modify it so that it doesn't show the annoying Settings button on the bottom right corner. Or at least doesn't appear unless you move your cursor down there.

[screenshot of new tab page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FltJs.png)

Comment: what have you read and tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [extension in the Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-wallpaper/pcnhoifipedfmkajgigiefacnnlkpdjd?hl=en), it doesn't look like the author linked the project to a homepage or an open source code repository such as GitHub.

That being said, if you really wanted to alter the extension, you can find the code on your computer, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14544700/3022863) regarding where to find the extension on your computer for various operating systems. A Google Chrome extension is simply HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: Hi nateyolles, thanks for your reply. I found the code but I have no idea what I'm doing! Newtab.js is the largest file so I'm guessing that's the file I'd have to alter, but it's certainly too big to post here. I was expecting this to be a relatively easy task but I'm a bit daunted now..

Comment: It's not an easy task. It's a head-on web technology programming task, complicated _severely_ by the fact that the code is machine-generated ([minified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming))) so it's no longer human-readable.