# What are the permissions for pinterest extension manifest.json?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, pinterest

I am making an extension like pinterest can anyone please tell me what are the permission for this extension should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ["Pin It" extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pin-it-button/gpdjojdkbbmdfjfahjcgigfpmkopogic) version 1.39.1 uses these permissions:

```
"*://*/*", "notifications", "cookies", "tabs", "storage", "contextMenus", "background"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @ivan Nokonoko

Comment: can you tell me please 
does pinit extension has background.js file?

Comment: @Programmer Yes it does. Once you install the extension, you can check its code. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543896/where-does-chrome-store-extensions)

Comment: Thank you for reply @Ivan Nokonoko but i am using win-32 and i am not able find appdata forlder.
Will you help me in this please

Comment: @Programmer The AppData folder is hidden by default. The path is usually C:\Users\ _YourUserName_ \AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions      it could be that instead of the folder Default it uses one of the Profile folders.