# How can I measure pixels in Chrome without an extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, pixel, measurement

Due to security limitations at work, I am not allowed to install Chrome extensions. Chrome has a ruler built in to the developer tools, but I can't figure out how to define start and end points like a ruler would permit.

Are there any tools or techniques for measuring pixels that don't require installing a Chrome extension?

Comment: Some of my coworkers take screenshots, paste them into MS Paint, draw a 1px line at the start point, and move that line with arrow keys (while counting) until they reach the endpoint. >_<

Comment: You could use the console and take the difference between offsets?
`footer.offsetTop - header.offsetTop`. Seems a little tedious though

Comment: I would also recommend fighting to fix the "security" policy of not being able to install tools you need. If you're already a developer, you're creating trusted code for other people to use so you better be trusted in that company already!

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You could create your own ruler functionality and paste it into the console. Here's a basic example:

```js
var fromX, fromY;
var svg = document.createElementNS ('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',"svg");
svg.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; top:0;left:0;height: " + document.body.clientHeight + "px;width: 100%");
var line = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','line');
line.setAttribute("style", "stroke-width: 4; stroke: red");

svg.appendChild(line);
document.body.appendChild(svg);

document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
  fromX = e.pageX;
  fromY = e.pageY;
});

document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  if (fromX === undefined) {
    return;
  }

  line.setAttribute("x1", fromX);
  line.setAttribute("x2", e.pageX);
  line.setAttribute("y1", fromY);
  line.setAttribute("y2", e.pageY);

  console.log(
    [fromX, fromY], " to ", [e.pageX, e.pageY], "Distance:",
    Math.sqrt(Math.pow(fromX - e.pageX, 2) + Math.pow(fromY - e.pageY, 2))
  );
});

document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
  fromX = undefined;
  fromY = undefined;
});
```

You could also save it as a [snippet](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/snippets/?hl=en).

Chrome extension code is also just JavaScript, so you can [find the code used by the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543896/where-does-chrome-store-extensions) and save that as a snippet. The downside here is that the code might be compressed, and rely on features that aren't normally available in the browser.

Comment: Ah yes, creating an SVG line overlay is another option I forgot to consider. Nice one.

Comment: I can see the Distance being logged in the console. But I don't see the red line (which I assume should be shown). Any idea what could be causing this ?

Comment: @DavidNouls I just tried the code again in Chrome, and it works fine for me... Any error messages? Can you inspect the page? At the bottom of the body tag there should be something like this: `<svg style="position: absolute; top:0;left:0;height: 505px;width: 100%"><line style="stroke-width: 4; stroke: red" x1="204" x2="756" y1="316" y2="156"></line></svg>`

Answer (score 41):

If you are not looking for exact measurements, but a ballpark estimate, a tool I use to measure pixels on Chrome without using a Chrome extension is the **macOS** screenshot tool.

Press *Command + shift + 4*, click and drag to measure pixels, and press **ESC** or right-click (if left is your primary mouse button) to prevent screenshot from being taken.

[Here's more info](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/how-to-osx-screen-shot-ruler)

According to link, you can zoom in apparently while in screenshot mode before taking a measurement, but I haven't tried it before.

Comment: That's a great and simple solution, thanks for that

Comment: And if you don't want the screenshot to be saved anywhere (like your Desktop), you can use *Command + **Control** + Shift + 4* which will save any screenshot just to your clipboard. That way there's no need the press ESC or right-click to prevent the screenshot from being taken.

Comment: [Lightshot screenshot](https://app.prntscr.com/en/index.html) does this too.

Answer (score 9):

Another way to measure pixel in chrome without extension is:

- Open Developer tool by pressing F12 in window or mouse right click + inspect element
- Inspect element in the browser to measure
- Open Computed tab and mouse over on blocks to see highlighted area in browse.

[image: for example see attached screen here]

Comment: This is by far the quickest option

Comment: I'm often trying to measure to/from the baseline of text components which makes this approach much less feasible. Thanks though!

Answer (score 3):

I think the best you can do without any extensions is a mixture of using the ruler with Inspector, the Computed metrics panel, and the Command Line API to view offsets (as per @amza's suggestion).

In the following screenshot, I have inspected `mainbar` element of this page. You can see the pixel offset from the top-left, but the values aren't shown unfortunately. You can access the five most recently inspected elements in the Console using the variables `$0-$4`. In this case, I use `$0`, which is the currently selected one. The `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` will give you the corresponding values that match what you see on the ruler. The Computing metrics panel shows the dimensions, including the padding, border and margin values. In this case, there's no outer values, but you would add those on to the `728x1032` dimension you see if there were.

Something like [Page Ruler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-ruler/jlpkojjdgbllmedoapgfodplfhcbnbpn?hl=en) would be a lot easier, but given your limitation it's not possible.

[image: Console Ruler]

Comment: I'm often trying to measure to/from the baseline of text components which makes this approach much less feasible. Thanks though!

Comment: @adamdport Yes, in that case you are better off with a drawing tool like other suggestion.