# Are chrome extensions saved securely? How can I encrypt them?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been developing a chrome extension and now I want to create version 2 with database support. For this I am going to use Firebase.

I need to create a file in my extension where I add the details about the firebase connection, api key and url etc..

After reading this question: [Where does Chrome store extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543896/where-does-chrome-store-extensions)

I went to look for mine. and boom there it was. I could open the files for the extensions and see the details I added about my firebase connection.

However, I am unsure as to whether I could see it because I am the developer and its on my machine. I do not like the idea of having my access keys available nor url.

Not that I think anyone would sabotage it, but I would hate to be billed for over usage of my requests etc..

Comment: like all software that runs locally, there is no way to prevent a curious user to find your source and secrets.