# Google extension dosen't work after publish

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hi I made a little chrome extension for my self to use and wanted to publish it so i can put it on my portfolio.When i had it locally everything worked fine but after trying to download the publish version and trying to open the popup it says 
"Your file was not found It may have been moved or deleted.
ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

this is my manifest

```
{
 "manifest_version": 2,

 "name": "",
 "description": "",
 "version": "1.0",

 "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "index.html"
 },
 "background": {
   "scripts": ["background.js"]
 },
 "permissions": [
   "background",
   "activeTab",
   "storage",
   "tabs",
 "http://*/*", 
 "https://*/*"
 ]
}
```

these are my files that i compressed to upload

```
background.js
icon.png
index.html
main.js
manifest.json
style.css
```

I turned off all my other extensions to make sure it wasn't the other extension causing the problem

Comment: Did you uninstall your local extension first?

Comment: Yes i installed the publish version of the extension both on a computer that dosent have local version and the one that dose have it

Comment: You can take a look in the installed extension's folder to see if all the files are in there. More details about where to find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543896/where-does-chrome-store-extensions

Comment: I remember I had similar issues before (with no reason whatsoever). Just give it some time, and try again. If it doesn't work, make some minor changes, and republish it and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @Titus i just did that and found that its missing the index.html for some reason but i had it compress to zip before uploading it