# How to check whether google chrome extension is installed in the browser through C#?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to check either user already install the chrome extension or not. Use code below directly check their chrome's extension, which I not sure it's possible or not.

I get this error with `HttpBrowserCapabilities`.

> **Error:** The type or namespace name HttpBrowserCapabilities does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

```cs
using System;
using System.Web;


namespace chromeCheck
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;
            if (browser.Browser == "chrome")
            {
                //check for extension alert user if not found the extension
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Due to various security concerns, even inside Chrome itself websites should not be able to detect if you have specific extension enabled, let alone an external C# program.

Can you expand on why you require this functionality? Maybe there are other approaches to this.

Comment: I have a c# app working with a chrome extension.  The chrome extension is required to get the desired output in the respective c# app.  Therefore, it is necessary to know whether the chrome extension has been installed through the c# app.

Comment: How do the C# app and the extension communicate? Are you able to use that communication to check if the extension is running? Aka, lack of communication means extension isn't working

Comment: The c# app and the chrome extension communicate through webSocket.

Comment: Okay, I did a little bit more of research, you have two options really:

1. If there is no webSocket communication there is either no extension installed, or browser isnt launched ( asuming that the C# app is the webSocket server ).

2.  Using C#, check for extensions in the Chrome AppData 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543896/where-does-chrome-store-extensions

Comment: Ok.Through the first option you mentioned, I can try to get a response from this extension to the c# app and check the relevant condition through that, right?